# Auto-increment variable in While Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner in vba and I would like a script for add 1 rule on all line(201 lines).

My counter is `i` and I want insert this `i` for an automatic increment in my worksheet

I don't know why I can't insert a variable?

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Byte
    i = 2

    While (i <= 202)
        Range("Hi,Hi:Ji,Mi:Pi").Select      '<--- insert my "i" here
        Range("Mi").Activate '<---here

        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, _
        Formula1:="=$G$i" '< ---here

        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 192
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With

        Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range("Hi,Hi:Ji,Mi:Pi")` with variable can be written as

```
Range("H" & i & ",H" & i & ":J" & i & ",M" & i & ":P" & i)
```

Similarly for the rest.

Basically `Range("A1")` can be written as `Range("A" & i)`

Also you do not need to use `.Select` to perform an action. In most of the cases, you can directly work with the object. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179)